# Stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document when trying to getText

Tags: java, selenium, staleelementreferenceexception

i've tried different ways to solve this problem. Here's the current code:

```
private static List<String> getDrillOptionAfter(WebDriver driver, String from) {
        List<WebElement> menus = getDrillOptionElms(driver, from);
        List<String> drillOptions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < menus.size(); i++) {
            boolean staleElement = true;
            while(staleElement) {
                try {
                    drillOptions.add(menus.get(i).getText());
                    staleElement = false;
                } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                    drillOptions.add(menus.get(i).getText());
                    staleElement =true;
                }
            }
            }
        return drillOptions;
    }
```

The code tries to get the text of dropdown options.
Also, in debug mode code works perfectly sometimes.

Comment: Does the `getDrillOptionElms` returning all the menu option elements successfully?

Comment: @supputuri Yes! it does.

Comment: Not related to staleElement but , `List<String> drillOptions = new ArrayList<>();` should this be `List<String> drillOptions = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: `menus.get(i)` is this returning the element or the exception? Have you tried with `menus.get(i).get_attribute('textContent')`?

Comment: Please share code of `getDrillOptionElms` method.